# DataFrame attribute error when writing multiple csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, api, dataframe

I'm trying to extract the daily OHLCV data for over 1,000 coins from the cryptocompare api and write those data to csv files;I have managed to write the daily_OHLCV function and it performs well if I call the function on individual coin, say daily_OHLCV('BTC','USD').

However, as I imported the ticker list of the 1000 coins from a csv file and tried to use a for loop to call the daily_OHLCV function for each of the ticker in the list, the code doesn't work and the error message says 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time', which has never appeared if I manually input the ticker into identifier.How can I fix this attribute error?

```
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import json
import csv
import os
import os.path

with open ('ICO-list.csv',"r")as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    ico_ticker_list=[]
    for row in reader:
        ticker=row[2]
        ico_ticker_list.append(ticker)

def daily_OHLCV(symbol, comparison_symbol, allData='true'):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym={}&tsym={}&allData=true'\
        .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper())
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()['Data']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
    path=os.path.expanduser('~')
    csvfile=os.path.join(path,'Desktop','Research','daily OHLCV','{}.csv'.format(symbol))
    export_csv=df.to_csv(csvfile,na_rep='NA',index=None,header=True)


for item in ico_ticker_list:
    daily_OHLCV(item,'USD')
```

Much appreciated if someone can help fix this problem to successfully call the function and generate corresponding csv file for all tickers in the ico_ticker_list

Answer (score 0):

in this line you are trying to read **time** column in **dataframe**

```
df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
```

'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'time' error means your dataframe doesn't have this column.
this can be because your api response doesn't have the particular data field relevant to **time**.
check the api response before create the dataframe and get the column names from `df.columns` and confirm the time column is exist.

Comment: I tried calling the function by manually input the ticker and there is a "time" column in the csv file generated, but when I tried calling the function using the for loop, it fails.

Comment: did you compare  the api response when manually input the ticker and while using loop.